# Using asyncio.wait, my can't I tell if my Event.wait task is in done or pending?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm receiving messages in a loop, and I want the loop to be cancel-able, so I'm using an `asyncio.Event` object to act as a flag for when the loop should exit, like this:

```
class MyThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.quit = asyncio.Event

    async def loop(self):
        while True:
            t1 = self.quit.Wait()
            t2 = self.recv_message()
            done, pending = asyncio.wait([t1, t2], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

            if t1 in done:
                break
```

The problem is that `t1 in done` returns `False`, even when `t1` is in `done`.  Sticking a breakpoint just before that `if` statement, I can see that `t1` looks like this:

```
(Pdb) p t1
<coroutine object Event.wait at 0x7fcff72ed340>
```

But `done` looks like this:

```
{<Task finished name='Task-95' coro=<Event.wait() done, defined at /usr/lib64/python3.8/asyncio/locks.py:296> result=True>}
```

There are a number of ways to work around this, of course.  I can write:

```
if t2 not in done:
```

Which seems to work correctly. I could also check for `self.quit.is_set()`. But why doesn't this `t1 in done` test work the way I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But why doesn't this `t1 in done` test work the way I expect?

Because `asyncio.wait` accepts any kind of *awaitable* objects, those that work with the `await` keyword, and most notably objects obtained by calling an `async def`. The objects it returns are *futures*, subclasses of `asyncio.Future`, most notably `Task` instances. Futures can run in the background and support an array of methods which enable `wait`, such as `add_done_callback`, `result`, etc.

The first thing `asyncio.wait` does with the awaitables it receives is convert them to futures using `asyncio.ensure_future`, which turns coroutine objects into tasks, and in general other awaitables into appropriate types of future. It works with futures from then on, and it returns them. This confusion is even described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait), even prompting the devs to deprecate passing non-futures to `asyncio.wait`.

The workaround that will enable `t1 in done` to work is for you to call `ensure_future` (or `create_task` when you know you're dealing with a coroutine yourself):

```
t1 = asyncio.ensure_future(self.quit.Wait())
t2 = asyncio.ensure_future(self.recv_message())
```

On a side note, you don't need an event to make the loop cancelable, you could use cancelation:

```
class MyThing:
    def __init__(self):
        # cancel the loop_task with self.loop_task.cancel()
        self.loop_task = None

    async def loop(self):
        self.loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop())
        await self.loop_task

    async def _loop(self):
        while True:
            await self.recv_message()
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran into problems cancelling (I need to make sure I close sockets in that case), but I think the solution you've presented here suggests a way to do that correctly.

Comment: @larsks Closing of sockets is normally handled via the `with` statement which ensures cleanup or, failing that, `try` and `finally`. When a task is canceled, it is woken up by injecting a `CancelledError` at the innermost `await` on which it got suspended. How it proceeds from there is up to the task, but in general it should use `finally` or equivalent to release resources, and leave the `CancelledError` to propagate to top-level.